# What is the name of a number ending with zero's?

Tags: terminology

I am currently writing a very specific graph of a function implementation. The graph can have min/max values e.g. $134$ and $1876$ respectively.
I'm calculating "nice" numbers. For min/max they are $100$ and $1900$ respectively.

Is there a commonly used name for such a number?

Comment: Sometimes such a number is called a *round* number.

Comment: Sometimes, one might even call them multiples of 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're exact multiples of powers of ten; they're also rounded to fewer significant figures. The benefit is to rapid human interpretation of annotation.

I haven't heard of an established term for such a pair, but "reduced precision bracket" might be a good descriptor.

Comment: I like the descriptive "ReducedPrecision" name. I will use this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are called multiples of $10$ [exclamation mark,exclamation mark,exclamation mark]

Comment: Not necesarily. A range of (12345, 12399) may round to (12300, 12400).

Comment: Still a power of ten, I see :).

Comment: I don't think they are. $10!!!$ is *far* larger than $1900$.

Comment: I have heard about factorials, and I've heard about double factorials (although those are most commonly used on odd numbers). However, I've never seen a triple factorial. What does that mean?

Comment: See [The Law of Exclamation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Law_of_Exclamation)!!!!!

Comment: Or for Pratchett fans, 10[urinating dog][urinating dog][urinating dog]

Comment: Or, also for Pratchett fans, 10[the sure sign of a diseased mind].

Answer (score 1):

Round numbers for ...

... Normal people: 100, 1000, 50000

... Computer scientists: 8, 32, 256, 65536

... American election losers: 52.9%

... Food retailers: 99 cents; 3:59 EUR

... Booksellers: 14,80 DM; 78 DM

... Choirs: 5, 10, 25, 75, 175

... Mathematicians: $\pi$, $e$, $2 \sqrt{2}$

... Car Dealers: 24800 DM; 38000 DM

... Ministers of Finance: -2 billion euro, -10 billion € / year

... Right idiots: 1889 1923 1933

... Carnival Teams: 11, 111

... Taxmen: 3.2 million; 2.9 billion

... American election winners: 47.2%

... Satanists: 6.66; 66.6; 666

... Physicists: $3 \cdot 10^8$, $2.4 \cdot 10^{-23}$

... Verbal eroticists: 0190 422 422

... Electricians: 9, 12, 110, 220, 380

... Left morons: 1917 1922 1957

... Towns: 750, 800, 1200

... Motorists: 121, 911, 106

Original: http://www.janko.at/Humor/Wissenschaft/Runde%20Zahlen.htm

Comment: Not sure why.. but I read that as France Finance

Comment: I love the way "grocer" in English matches to "Lebensmitteleinzelhändler" in German.